# Date Picker in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use Data Picker for a datatime field in my MVC-Form

I am using the Following code to get the Data time value,

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter the Absence Start Date")]
    [StringLength(20,ErrorMessage="The Format must not exceed 50 Characaters")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime )]
    [Display(Name="Absence Start Date")]
    public DateTime AbsenceStartDate{get;set;}
```

But I want to have datapicker controls beside the textbox. How could I do that?

Any help

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good client-side datepicker is provided in the jQuery UI library: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

You may use jQuery UI datepicker with DateTime editor template in asp.net mvc. Take a look at [Sample](http://www.nickharris.net/2010/08/asp-net-mvc-editor-template-for-jquery-datepicker/). Actually, you SHOULD use editor-template

Answer (score 0):

I would use a client-side date picker.  There are plenty available for jQuery.  Then you use ASP.NET MVC to validate the input as text in the form of a date..

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method as below:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString CalenderTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, "{0:M/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker text" });
    }
```

Then use in view as below:

```
@Html.CalenderTextBoxFor(model => model.Employee.HireDate)
```